# Google play console.Add new apk.menu publish this app not found

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, apk, publish

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCslw.jpg)

i'm added new apk file.when click ready to publish but not found menu publish this app.

Answer (score 0):

If you uploaded a new app version and can't save it, I think there is an error on the "Product details" tab.

Comment: Tab product details it is ok.status is ready to publish but menu publish this app not found.

Comment: it might take some time to reflect changes, try after some time https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=en